# Android Visible view

Tags: java, android

we are using this code to visible view :

```
btnviewarray[x].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int secid=v.getId();
        for(int zt=0;bzt<dcountlinks;bzt++)
        {
            if(mybtnids[zt]==secid)
            {
                myid=zt;
            }
        }
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), dcountpeople[myid], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        lnralllinksview.VISIBLE(View.GONE);
        lnrallpeopleview.VISIBLE(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

when this code running we are getting Method call Excepted error

Comment: *we are getting Method call Excepted error* - On which code line exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like

```
lnralllinksview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
lnrallpeopleview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: thank you very much , that's worked , i am accept your answer in 8 min :) <3

Answer (score 1):

**Wrong**

```
 lnralllinksview.VISIBLE(View.GONE);
 lnrallpeopleview.VISIBLE(View.GONE);
```

**Perfect**

```
lnralllinksview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
lnrallpeopleview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**FYI**

Read **[setVisibility](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int))**